# Calculating Velocity Between Two Points

Tags: c#, math

I have an enemy ship and a player ship.

I would like the enemy ship to always fly towards the player in a direct line, at all times, even when the player is moving.

I'm going about this using the Ray class for C# XNA.

I have two vector coordinates, the position/origin of the ray (the players current position), and the Direction of the ray (the enemy's current position). I'd like the enemy's position to gradually move towards the players position.

I have this code so far.

```
enemyPlayerTrack.Position = playerPos;
enemyPlayerTrack.Direction = enemyPos;
```

I'm unsure whether I need another vector for velocity or not.

In the end, the enemy will be drawn to the screen with a new position with this code:

```
enemyWorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(x, y, z));
```

Without a mathematical background, I'm having trouble creating a velocity to bridge the two vectors closer and closer.

Comment: Game development **requires** at least *some* math background. Try, from thousands of books: Christopher Tremblay. Mathematics for Game Developers. Course Technology, 2004. ISBN 9781592000388

Comment: I agree with the previous commentors - particularly concentrate on trigonometry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We choose some speed `s`. Then the direction of the player from the enemy is:

```
dir_x = player_x - enemy_x
dir_y = player_y - enemy_y
```

Overall speed s = sqrt(vel_x^2 + vel_y)^2, so we scale the dir vector to give us the speed:

```
factor = s / sqrt(dir_x^2 + dir_y^2)
vel_x = dir_x * factor
vel_y = dir_y * factor
```

So now the enemy will always fly at the same speed, directed towards the player. But if the player is near the enemy, the enemy will overshoot and keep bouncing back and forth over the player. So we limit the speed:

```
distance = sqrt(dir_x^2 + dir_y^2)
delay_to_reaching_player = 2    // some measure of time
enemy_speed = min(s, distance/delay_to_reaching_player)
```

This way, by setting the delay, the enemy will slow down as it approaches the player, once it gets close enough to stop moving at its maximum speed (s).

Comment: How would I then implement that to the final movement code?

enemyWorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(vel_x, vel_y, z)); ???

Comment: slowing down? nah... RAMMING SPEED!!! ;p

Comment: The translation is the change in position, which is the velocity multiplied by the time increment. If you know how frequently the screen updates, use this (e.g. 0.01 seconds), but if you don't then it is better to capture the time since the last frame and use that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: For beginners, it's probably best to avoid needing collision code...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have XNA in front of me, so this is just pseudocode...

The total delta between the two should be simply:

```
var delta = playerPosition - enemyPosition;
```

This gives direction, but will usually have the wrong magnitude; so we can rescale that to a unit-vector via:

```
var magnitude = Math.Sqrt(delta.x * delta.x + delta.y * delta.y +
                  delta.z * delta.z); // however many dimensions you have...
var unitDelta = delta / magnitude; // assuming non-zero; if zero, don't move
var newVelocity = unitDelta * enemySpeed;
```

Note, however, that this defies momentum, and is very basic (it doesn't account for the player's velocity - it'll feel like the AI is stupid).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector from the enemy -> player, you basically have a translation that you can apply to the enemy to get it to jump to the players position. You need to get back to a 'unit' by normalising the vector which will set the vectors overall length to '1' but have it still point in the direction of the player, then you can multiply this value by the velocity you actually want to get a vector to translate the enemy by to move it towards the player

As people have already answered - to get a unit you need sum the products of both components of the vector and then take the square root. This ties to pythagoras theorem e.g.:

If you take the components of a vector say

`(2,2)`

Which would be this:

```
  2 
  ^
  |
  |
--> 2
```

And then draw a line between the origin (0,0) and the point where the vector ends meet - you get a triangle...

```
  2
  ^
 /|
/ |
--> 2
```

This line represents the magnitude of the vector, you take the sum of the squares of both components and then sqrt it to get the length of this line:

`2 * 2 + 2 * 2 = 8`

`sqrt(8) = 2.82`

So this vector is 2.82 long - meaning the 2 and 2 values are 2.82 times the size of a single unit vector

To get components that are '1' long or a 'unit', we need to normalise the vector - we do this by dividing each component by the magnitude

`2 / 2.82 = 0.70`

Which sounds about right - I know the angle of this vector is 45 degrees (up 2 across 2 must be a perfect diagonal) so you can check it using cosine or sine since cosine/sine provides the horizontal or vertical unit length of a vectors component for the given angle

`sin(45) or cos(45) = 0.70`

Spot on

So now you know that the angle towards the player uses a 1 length vector with the following components

`(0.7, 0.7)`

To move the enemy 3 units towards the player, you'd simply multiply the components by 3

`0.7 * 3 = 2.1`

So

`(2.1, 2.1)`

Would move the enemy 3 units towards the player in this physics step

Does this help at all?